# Pygame setup ubuntu

Tags: python, vim

I just wanted to start using Pygame in Ubuntu 16.10 .
First I wrote a code in Vim , now how to run Pygame . (I installed Pygame using command line .) 
Please help , I did not find any solution in the internet .

Answer (score 1):

Your post is a bit ambiguous. What code did you write and in what way did it not work?

In case you don't know, Pygame is a Python module, and the first step in using any Python module is by importing it in Python, i.e. `import pygame`.

If that works (i.e. doesn't raise an `ImportError`), then the module is successfully installed, and that's pretty much as far as Ubuntu itself is concerned. If you need help on how to make use of the module to build games, then you need to consult the particular module's documentation and tutorials, which can be found on its official website:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/

.. and countless other places on the internet. Just Google something like "pygame tutorial", or "getting started with pygame", or a more specific "how to [do so and so] in pygame".

On the other hand, if you're getting an `ImportError`, then maybe you're using the wrong version of Python. Pygame is only available for Python 2. So ensure you're running your scripts with correct version, i.e. use `python2 your_script.py` or `idle2 -r your_script.py`.

Comment: My mistake , instead of running "python 1.py " , I wrote "pygame 1.py".